# What are these buttons called?

Tags: images

What are these buttons called?

[image: Antipixel Valid XHTML] [image: Get Firefox] [image: Hacker / glider]

Comment: website example where these are used?

Comment: Man, I've been wondering this for years.  Great question.

Comment: OMG! It's my question again. It's been so long. *kiss*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're also sometimes called "chicklets" -- not to be confused with Chiclets, of course.

Comment: that's right +1 http://www.toprankblog.com/tools/rss-buttons/

Comment: That seems to be the most definite answer, so you get the credit =) Here's some info on chiclets, BTW, although it seems these are oriented to be social bookmarking buttons: http://www.chicklets.net/

Comment: I've never heard the term "chicklets" before :-/

Answer (score 5):

Those are called antipixel badges or antipixel buttons. They're also known as [brilliant buttons](http://www.lucazappa.com/brilliantMaker/buttonImage.php) or [steal these buttons](http://stealthesebuttons.terrababy.nl/).

> Originated by [antipixel.com](http://antipixel.com/blog/archives/2002/10/22/steal_these_buttons.html) and popularised by [gtmcknight.com](http://gtmcknight.com/buttons/), 80 x 15 buttons are quickly becoming a web standard as their popularity rises among big blog owners and other web enthusiasts.

They're typically only 80 pixels wide by 15 pixels high and have been floating around since late 2002.

Comment: These are definitely Antipixel buttons. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_badge for the note about the 80x15 size buttons.

Comment: Totally forgot the site of the quote when adding in all those links to the answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know they originated at Antipixel. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Other than just calling them buttons - I believe they could be a form of [Userbars](http://www.userbars.com/), however I cannot find a definitive definition of a Userbar.

Answer (score 1):

these buttons are called ... erm, buttons :)

example:

[**Free Firefox Button For Your Website**](http://www.downloadfirefoxbrowser.com/firefox_button.html)

Comment: "Buttons". Yep, that about covers it :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's just that they have a standard size, 80x15px, so I thought they might have a name.

Answer (score 1):

Badges, I think.  Wikipedia calls them [web badges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_badge).

For some reason I seem to remember seeing a different name, way back when I was hunting down ones to put on my website, but I can't remember it now.  (In case anyone asks: it wasn't "chicklets")

Comment: that's also correct ... and i too seem to remember them being called something else 'back in the days' :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use those for other purposes than buttons. You could simply use them as "designed for: " notes on a page. You could simply use them as pictures for some reason or another.  And anything else you can think of.  I think the official name would depend on the use.